# Replacing multiple values per cell in Pandas

Tags: list, python-2.7, pandas, dictionary, replace

I have the following column in a dataframe:

```
Q2
1 4
1 3
3 4 11 
1 4 6 15 16
```

I want to replace mutiple values in a cell, if present: `1` gets replaced by `Facebook`, `2` with `Instagram`, and so on.

I splitted the values as follows:

```
columns_to_split = 'Q2'

for c in columns_to_split:
    df[c] = df[c].str.split(' ')
```

which outputs

```
code                             
DSOKF31                          [1, 4]
DSOVH39                          [1, 3]
DSOVH05                          [3, 4, 16]
DSOVH23                          [1, 4, 6, 15, 16]
Name: Q2, dtype: object
```

but when trying to replace the multiple values with a dictionary as follows:

```
social_media_2 = {'1':'Facebook', '2':'Instagram', '3':'Twitter', '4':'Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, WhatsAPP, MSG, Facetime, IMO)', '5':'SnapChat', '6':'Imo', '7':'Badoo', '8':'Viber', '9':'Twoo', '10':'Linkedin', '11':'Flickr', '12':'Meetup', '13':'Tumblr', '14':'Pinterest', '15':'Yahoo', '16':'Gmail', '17':'Hotmail', '18':'M-Pesa', '19':'M-Shwari', '20':'KCB-Mpesa', '21':'Equitel', '22':'MobiKash', '23':'Airtel money', '24':'Orange Money', '25':'Mobile Bankig Accounts', '26':'Other specify'}

df['Q2'] = df['Q2'].replace(social_media_2)
```

I get the same output:

```
code                             
DSOKF31                          [1, 4]
DSOVH39                          [1, 3]
DSOVH05                          [3, 4, 16]
DSOVH23                          [1, 4, 6, 15, 16]
Name: Q2, dtype: object
```

How do I replace multiple values in one cell in this case?

Comment: Why is there a single column? Will it always be two values? Shouldn't that be two separate columns?

Comment: Yes, `[1, 2]` should become `['Facebook', 'Instagram']`, `[1, 3]` should become `['Facebook', 'Twitter']`, and so on. It won't always be two values, something like `[3, 4, 16]` and `[1, 4, 6, 15, 16]` is also in the dataset. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the number of items is varying, there isn't a lot of structure. Still, after you split the string, you can `apply` a function that maps a list into dictionary values:

```
In [36]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Q2': ['1 4', '1 3', '1 2 3']})

In [37]: df.Q2.str.split(' ').apply(lambda l: [social_media_2[e] for e in l])
Out[37]: 
0    [Facebook, Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, Wh...
1                                  [Facebook, Twitter]
2                       [Facebook, Instagram, Twitter]
Name: Q2, dtype: object
```

**Edit** Following Jezrael's excellent comment, here's a version that accounts for missing values as well:

```
In [58]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Q2': ['1 4', '1 3', '1 2 3', None]})

In [59]: df.Q2.str.split(' ').apply(lambda l: [] if type(l) != list else [social_media_2[e] for e in l])
Out[59]: 
0    [Facebook, Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, Wh...
1                                  [Facebook, Twitter]
2                       [Facebook, Instagram, Twitter]
3                                                   []
Name: Q2, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! I get `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable` on that loop however.

Comment: @JohnBoss Are you running it like I did above, or as `for c in columns_to_split:`? The loop will try to apply it to the columns `'Q'` and `'2'`, because `columns_to_split` is a string.

Comment: I ran it as above, and get `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`. (Well, I also read in my dataframe from an excel file, and the `social_media_2` variable is defined with a list of course.)

Comment: @JohnBoss Can you write the full error message? It should be several lines.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/replace.py", line 17, in <module>
    df.Q2.str.split(' ').apply(lambda l: [social_media_2[e] for e in l])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2220, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/src/inference.pyx", line 1088, in pandas.lib.map_infer (pandas/lib.c:62658)
  File "replace.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    df.Q2.str.split(' ').apply(lambda l: [social_media_2[e] for e in l])
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
[Finished in 1.6s with exit code 1]`

Comment: @JohnBoss Sorry, I don't know why. I'll delete the answer in a few minutes. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this definitely seems like the way to go, so please let me try to figure out what goes wrong here before you remove your answer.

Comment: Your solution works when I define the dataset as `df = pd.DataFrame({'Q2': ['1 4', '1 3', '1 2 3']})`. When I try to run it on my importer Excel sheet, I get the error message. So your answer if definitely correct. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohnBoss Sure. Could you post in your answer the outputs to `df.Q2.head` and `df.Q2.dtype`?

Comment: I think in column are some NaN values, so solution is a bit complicated - need apply list compehension only for non NaN values.

Comment: @jezrael Many thanks! That's a good idea - added a check to perform the map only on `list` types.

Comment: @AmiTavory - nice solution, only you can omit `split(' ')` and use `split()` only. ;)

Comment: @AmiTavory - no problem, I think if need output as list, the fastest and better solution is apply list comprehension as `stack` and `unstack`, but I didnt test it. Maybe you can add timings.

Comment: Amazing, guys. Thank you so much.

Comment: How can I zfill/pad each value within a single cell?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative solution:

```
In [45]: df
Out[45]:
            Q2
0          1 4
1          1 3
2       3 4 16
3  1 4 6 15 16

In [47]: (df.Q2.str.split(expand=True)
   ....:    .stack()
   ....:    .map(social_media_2)
   ....:    .unstack()
   ....:    .apply(lambda x: x.dropna().values.tolist(), axis=1)
   ....: )
Out[47]:
0                       [Facebook, Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, WhatsAPP, MSG, Facetime, IMO)]
1                                                                              [Facebook, Twitter]
2                 [Twitter, Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, WhatsAPP, MSG, Facetime, IMO), Gmail]
3    [Facebook, Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, WhatsAPP, MSG, Facetime, IMO), Imo, Yahoo, Gmail]
dtype: object
```

Explanation:

```
In [50]: df.Q2.str.split(expand=True).stack().map(social_media_2)
Out[50]:
0  0                                                          Facebook
   1    Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, WhatsAPP, MSG, Facetime, IMO)
1  0                                                          Facebook
   1                                                           Twitter
2  0                                                           Twitter
   1    Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, WhatsAPP, MSG, Facetime, IMO)
   2                                                             Gmail
3  0                                                          Facebook
   1    Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, WhatsAPP, MSG, Facetime, IMO)
   2                                                               Imo
   3                                                             Yahoo
   4                                                             Gmail
dtype: object

In [51]: df.Q2.str.split(expand=True).stack().map(social_media_2).unstack()
Out[51]:
          0                                                               1      2      3      4
0  Facebook  Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, WhatsAPP, MSG, Facetime, IMO)   None   None   None
1  Facebook                                                         Twitter   None   None   None
2   Twitter  Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, WhatsAPP, MSG, Facetime, IMO)  Gmail   None   None
3  Facebook  Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, WhatsAPP, MSG, Facetime, IMO)    Imo  Yahoo  Gmail
```

**Timing** against 40K rows DF:

```
In [86]: big = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [87]: big.shape
Out[87]: (40000, 1)

In [88]: %%timeit
   ....: (big.Q2.str.split(expand=True)
   ....:     .stack()
   ....:     .map(social_media_2)
   ....:     .unstack()
   ....:     .apply(lambda x: x.dropna().values.tolist(), axis=1)
   ....: )
   ....:
1 loop, best of 3: 19.6 s per loop

In [89]: %timeit big.Q2.str.split(' ').apply(lambda l: [social_media_2[e] for e in l])
10 loops, best of 3: 72.6 ms per loop
```

**Conclusion:** Ami's solution is approx. 270 times faster!

Comment: I think if need output as list, the fastest and better solution is apply list comprehension as `stack` and `unstack`, but I didnt test it. Maybe you can add timings.

Comment: @jezrael, do you mean Ami's solution or something different?

Comment: Yes, I think Ami solution vs your. Your is more pandaonic ;), but slowier, but maybe I am wrong, because I cannot test it now.

Comment: @jezrael, just added timings... Ami's solution is much faster

Comment: Thank you for testing. A few months ago I used similar solutions, but your is beeter only if need output as `DataFrame`. Good luck and +1

Comment: Ami's solution might be faster, but this alternative answer helps me a lot in understanding Panda's better. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If dont need `list` as output add only `regex=True` to `replace`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Q2': ['1 4', '1 3', '3 4 11']})
print (df)
       Q2
0     1 4
1     1 3
2  3 4 11

social_media_2 = {'1':'Facebook', '2':'Instagram', '3':'Twitter', '4':'Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, WhatsAPP, MSG, Facetime, IMO)', '5':'SnapChat', '6':'Imo', '7':'Badoo', '8':'Viber', '9':'Twoo', '10':'Linkedin', '11':'Flickr', '12':'Meetup', '13':'Tumblr', '14':'Pinterest', '15':'Yahoo', '16':'Gmail', '17':'Hotmail', '18':'M-Pesa', '19':'M-Shwari', '20':'KCB-Mpesa', '21':'Equitel', '22':'MobiKash', '23':'Airtel money', '24':'Orange Money', '25':'Mobile Bankig Accounts', '26':'Other specify'}
df['Q2'] = df['Q2'].replace(social_media_2, regex=True)
print (df)

                                                  Q2
0  Facebook Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, What...
1                                   Facebook Twitter
2  Twitter Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, Whats...
```

If need `lists`, use another solutions.

EDIT by comment:

You can [replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) whitespace by `;` and then it works nice:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Q2': ['1 4', '1 3', '3 4 11']})
print (df)
       Q2
0     1 4
1     1 3
2  3 4 11

df['Q2'] = df['Q2'].str.replace(' ',';')
print (df)
       Q2
0     1;4
1     1;3
2  3;4;11

social_media_2 = {'1':'Facebook', '2':'Instagram', '3':'Twitter', '4':'Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, WhatsAPP, MSG, Facetime, IMO)', '5':'SnapChat', '6':'Imo', '7':'Badoo', '8':'Viber', '9':'Twoo', '10':'Linkedin', '11':'Flickr', '12':'Meetup', '13':'Tumblr', '14':'Pinterest', '15':'Yahoo', '16':'Gmail', '17':'Hotmail', '18':'M-Pesa', '19':'M-Shwari', '20':'KCB-Mpesa', '21':'Equitel', '22':'MobiKash', '23':'Airtel money', '24':'Orange Money', '25':'Mobile Bankig Accounts', '26':'Other specify'}
df['Q2'] = df['Q2'].replace(social_media_2, regex=True)
print (df)
                                                  Q2
0  Facebook;Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, What...
1                                   Facebook;Twitter
2  Twitter;Messenger (Google hangout, Tagg, Whats...
```

EDIT1:

Tou can also a bit change `dict` by adding `;` to `keys` and then replace by double `;`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Q2': ['1 2', '1 3', '3 2 11']})
print (df)
       Q2
0     1 2
1     1 3
2  3 2 11

df['Q2'] = df['Q2'].str.replace(' ',';;') + ';'
print (df)
          Q2
0      1;;2;
1      1;;3;
2  3;;2;;11;

social_media_2 = {'1':'Fa', '2':'I', '3':'T', '11':'KL'}
#add ; to keys in dict
social_media_2 = dict((key + ';', value) for (key, value) in social_media_2.items())
print (social_media_2)
{'1;': 'Fa', '2;': 'I', '3;': 'T', '11;': 'KL'}
df['Q2'] = df['Q2'].replace(social_media_2, regex=True)
print (df)
        Q2
0     Fa;I
1     Fa;T
2  T;I;1Fa
```

Comment: Thank you. I would like a delimiter between the answers that is not a space, like ';', but otherwise this also does what I need.

Comment: I add solution, please check it.

Comment: I just figured out I can easily do that by first replacing the spaces with a semicolon with `df['Q2'] = df['Q2'].replace(' ','; ', regex=True)`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That did the trick! The only thing is that double digits like '19' now get mapped to '1' and '9' in the dictionary (so '19' becomes 'FacebookTwoo', which are the values for '1' and '9', not the value for '19'. So I think I need lists after all, unless I can find a smart regex string that accounts for single and double digits in this case.

Comment: I add new solution, please check it.